# how to get dockbarx previews in xfce panel without compiz

Tags: xfce-panel, dockbarx

A lot of questions have been covered here about getting dockbarx previews working in xfce with compiz but I'd like to get previews working using the xfwm standard compositing to keep things lightweight. xfce

Comment: No, I don't think this is possible. This is probably a feature request that should be addressed at https://bugzilla.xfce.org/ .